# HID over GATT server on Windows IoT Core

Tags: hid, windows-10-iot-core, gatt

I tried to create a HID over GATT device with Windows IoT Core on my Raspberry Pi 3. I followed the documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server which is not 100% accurate for the release version of the 15063 SDK but it is the only documentation I could find.

However, when calling

```cs
GattServiceProviderResult result = await GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync(
            GattServiceUuids.HumanInterfaceDevice);
```

I get

```cs
result.Error == BluetoothError.DisabledByPolicy
```

I added the Bluetooth capability to my package manifest, I'm running build 15063 and I'm using 15063 as the minimum SDK version. I tried to use the code in a Background App.

Also - I don't understand the error message. I haven't done anything with policies; I'm not running the Pro version of Windows IoT Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, running a HID service is not allowed according to [this Microsoft answer on github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/64#issuecomment-296770406).

> Unfortunately, HID is currently protected as a reserved service, which prevents it from being implemented by a 3rd party application. Please share details on the scenario, and we will discuss it internally.

The documentation for GATT Server on UWP is still being worked on (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/63)

Comment: In the github issue, mtbeaver did mention that the restriction will get removed in next release. Probably it is already removed.